# How to make an angular material input look similar to a button?

Tags: angular, button, input, angular-material

Is there any css style that I can use to make an angular material input resemble with a button?

The reason for needing this is the following:

I want to create filters as in airbnb and for example I use different components(not all my filters can be implemented using a button):

```
   1. datepicker which is embedded in an input
   2. button which opens a mat-menu for price choosing using a slider
   3. mat-select with mat options for choosing one or several categories
```

And because datepicker can't be opened by clicking a button (only with an input) and the mat-select that I have added for categories can't be replaced by a button, and so on, I thought about the idea of giving the components a similar look and feel, so that they look approximately the same as for example on airbnb.

Comment: why not just use a button? https://material.angular.io/components/button/overview

Comment: Why? Are you trying to confuse your users so they don't realize it's an input field and instead click on on it thinking it's a button? I'm kidding around of course, but would also like to understand why you think you should do this, because to me it sounds like a very bad idea.

Comment: I added the reasons in the question. If my idea is bad, maybe you could give me some suggestions or other ideas. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is a little unclear as to what you are looking for as stated by @Ayyash you could use a button. If you just mean styled similarly with a border and rounded corners you could use a Form Field with appearance set to outline: `<mat-form-field appearance="outline">`

[image]

More information can be found [here](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview).

If you are just looking at adding css to the element to make it look similar to the buttons you are using you can [use developer tools to inspect the element](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/css/) and copy the css you want. You may need to add !important after the css to make it override what comes bundled with the material input. e.g `color: #000000 !important;`

Comment: This solution is great. Thank you very much!